# Linux: Merging multiple files, each on a new line

Tags: linux, bash

I am using **cat *.txt** to merge multiple txt files into one, but I need each file to be on a separate line.

What is the best way to merge files with each file appearing on a new line?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: No it doesn't.  Try `echo -n a > a.txt; echo -n b > b.txt; cat a.txt b.txt`.

Comment: @ephemient: `echo "some text" > text.txt; file text.txt; echo -n "some text" > text.txt; file text.txt`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: So?  The point is that `cat` doesn't add any newlines between files.  If a file ends in a newline (as most UNIX text files do), then fine; if not, then not.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

just use awk

```
awk 'FNR==1{print ""}1' *.txt
```

Comment: Love this.  I adapted it to produce a comment so I can tell what file each section of the new file came from: awk 'FNR==1{ printf ("# %s\n", ARGV[ARGIND]) }1'  Thanks for introducing me to awk.  I'm combining .coffee files so I can avoid coffee's --merge and thus get a working source map.

Comment: Would suggest the following edit to not include a line break at the top of the results: `awk 'FNR==1&&NR!=1{print ""}1' *.txt`

Comment: Could we add it at the end of each file as well? If so, could we add 2 new lines instead of one?

Answer (score 25):

If you have a `paste` that supports it,

```
paste --delimiter=\\n --serial *.txt
```

does a really great job

Comment: This is one of the fastest methods of file concatenation I have ever tested. Great idea...

Comment: IMO best solution. Both `-d` and `-s` are posix-specified, so there shouldn't be a `paste` not supporting them. This solution really needs more votes.

Comment: +1 excellent! thanks a Million. exact question i had and the perfect ans!

Comment: Holy heck that is FAST!!

Comment: `echo * | xargs paste -s -d \n > foo.txt` to avoid argument list too long error.

Comment: On MacOS bash, the main answer above didn't work, but `paste -d=\\n -s *.chunk.txt > all.txt` did.

Answer (score 17):

You can iterate through each file with a for loop:

```
for filename in *.txt; do
    # each time through the loop, ${filename} will hold the name
    # of the next *.txt file.  You can then arbitrarily process
    # each file
    cat "${filename}"
    echo

# You can add redirection after the done (which ends the
# for loop).  Any output within the for loop will be sent to
# the redirection specified here
done > output_file
```

Comment: This will choke on files that have a space in the filename.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquezAbrams - thanks for the reminder (I don't use spaces in my names so I usually forget that).  Anyway, I've updated my example to handle that properly.

Comment: I picked the awk solution, but this will definitely come in useful for other scripts. Thanks.

Comment: best safe and expandable solution

Answer (score 7):

```
for file in *.txt
do
  cat "$file"
  echo
done > newfile
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you want a line break between files.

```
for file in *.txt
do
   cat "$file" >> result
   echo >> result
done
```