# How to append contents of multiple files into one file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to copy the contents of five files to one file as is. I tried doing it using cp for each file. But that overwrites the contents copied from the previous file. I also tried

```
paste -d "\n" 1.txt 0.txt
```

and it did not work.

I want my script to add the newline at the end of each text file.

eg. Files 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt. Put contents of 1,2,3 in 0.txt

How do I do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating Files And Insert New Line In Between Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183191/concatenating-files-and-insert-new-line-in-between-files)

Comment: Another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576693/linux-merging-multiple-files-each-on-a-new-line

Answer (score 388, accepted):

You need the `cat` (short for concatenate) command, with shell redirection (`>`) into your output file

```
cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 0.txt
```

Comment: should be >> right ? and also why is there a newline before all the text in my 0.txt file ?

Comment: did you want to preserve the content of 0.txt?

Comment: @blasto it depends.  You would use `>>` to _append_ one file onto another, where `>` _overwrites_ the output file with whatever's directed into it.  As for the newline, is there a newline as the first character in file `1.txt`?  You can find out by using `od -c`, and seeing if the first character is a `\n`.

Comment: @radical7 Thanks. Actually, my files are like foo_1, foo_2, foo_3. I tried to modify your code as - cat "$filename_"{1,2,3}".txt" , but it did not work.

Comment: @blasto You're definitely heading in the right direction.  Bash certainly accepts the form `{...}` for filename matching, so perhaps the quotes messed things up a bit in your script?  I always try working with things like this using `ls` in a shell.  When I get the command right, I just cut-n-paste it into a script as is. You might also find the `-x` option useful in your scripts - it will echo the expanded commands in the script before execution.

Comment: To maybe stop somebody from making the same mistake: `cat 1.txt 2.txt > 1.txt` will just override `1.txt` with the content of `2.txt`. It does *not* merge the two files into the first one.

Comment: `cat $(ls *.txt) > 0.txt` should work too, assuming that only the desired `.txt` are in the directory.

Comment: Wish I'd seen this PSA before now @RicoOcepek 

Comment: @Codemonkey Should have written it in bold  Always funny when suddenly 6 years after posting something someone actually reads it

Answer (score 120):

Another option, for those of you who still stumble upon this post like I did, is to use `find -exec`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} + >> output.file
```

In my case, I needed a more robust option that would look through multiple subdirectories so I chose to use `find`. Breaking it down:

```
find .
```

Look within the current working directory.

```
-type f
```

Only interested in files, not directories, etc.

```
-name '*.txt'
```

Whittle down the result set by name

```
-exec cat {} +
```

Execute the cat command for each result. "+" means only 1 instance of `cat` is spawned (thx @gniourf_gniourf)

```
 >> output.file
```

As explained in other answers, append the cat-ed contents to the end of an output file.

Comment: There are lots of flaws in this answer. First, the wildcard `*.txt` must be quoted (otherwise, the whole `find` command, as written, is useless). Another flaw comes from a gross misconception: the command that is executed _is not_ `cat >> 0.txt {}`, but `cat {}`.  Your command is in fact equivalent to `{ find . -type f -name *.txt -exec cat '{}' \; ; } >> 0.txt` (I added grouping so that you realize what's really happening). Another flaw is that `find` is going to find the file `0.txt`, and `cat` will complain by saying that _input file is output file_.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. My case was a little bit different and I hadn't thought of some of those gotchas as applied to this case.

Comment: You should put `>> output.file` at the end of your command, so that you don't induce anybody (including yourself) into thinking that `find` will execute `cat {} >> output.file` for every found file.

Comment: Starting to look really good! One final suggestion: use `-exec cat {} +` instead of `-exec cat {} \;`, so that only one instance of `cat` is spawned with several arguments ([`+` is specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)).

Comment: Good answer and word of warning - I modified mine to: `find . -type f -exec cat {} + >> outputfile.txt` and couldn't figure out why my output file wouldn't stop growing into the gigs even though the directory was only 50 megs. It was because I kept appending outputfile.txt to itself! So just make sure to name that file correctly or place it in another directory entirely to avoid this.

Comment: I suppose a more simple command would be 

`(find . -type f -name "f*.log*" |xargs cat) > result.log`

Comment: @KIR this can be a problem if there are way too many files, enough to get an `Argument list too long` error.

Comment: Another sugestion:`{}` should be quoted in order to prevent shell interpretation.  It should be `-exec cat '{}' `

Answer (score 53):

if you have a certain output type then do something like this

```
cat /path/to/files/*.txt >> finalout.txt
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you are losing the possibility to maintain merge order though. This may affect you if you have your files named, eg. `file_1`, `file_2`, … `file_11`, because of the natural order how files are sorted.

Answer (score 23):

If all your files are named similarly you could simply do:

```
cat *.log >> output.log
```

Answer (score 19):

If all your files are in single directory you can simply do

`cat * > 0.txt`

Files 1.txt,2.txt, .. will go into 0.txt

Comment: Already answered by Eswar. Keep in mind that you are losing the possibility to maintain merge order though. This may affect you if you have your files named, eg. `file_1`, `file_2`, … `file_11`, because of the natural order how files are sorted.

Answer (score 17):

```
for i in {1..3}; do cat "$i.txt" >> 0.txt; done
```

I found this page because I needed to join 952 files together into one.  I found this to work much better if you have many files.  This will do a loop for however many numbers you need and cat each one using >> to append onto the end of 0.txt.

Edit:

as brought up in the comments:

```
cat {1..3}.txt >> 0.txt
```

or

```
cat {0..3}.txt >> all.txt
```

Comment: you could use brace expansion in bash to write cat {1,2,3}.txt >> 0.txt

Answer (score 6):

Another option is `sed`:

```
sed r 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > merge.txt
```

Or...

```
sed h 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > merge.txt
```

Or...

```
sed -n p 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > merge.txt # -n is mandatory here
```

Or without redirection ...

```
sed wmerge.txt 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

Note that last line write also `merge.txt` (not `wmerge.txt`!). You can use `w"merge.txt"` to avoid confusion with the file name, and `-n` for silent output.

Of course, you can also shorten the file list with wildcards. For instance, in case of numbered files as in the above examples, you can specify the range with braces in this way:

```
sed -n w"merge.txt" {1..3}.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

if your files contain **headers** and you want remove them in the output file, you can use:

```
for f in `ls *.txt`; do sed '2,$!d' $f >> 0.out; done
```

Answer (score 4):

All of the (text-) files into one

```
find . | xargs cat > outfile
```

xargs makes the output-lines of find .  the arguments of cat.

find has many options, like -name '*.txt' or -type.

you should check them out if you want to use it in your pipeline

Comment: You should explain what your command does. Btw, you should use find with --print0 and xargs with -0 in order to avoid some caveats with special filenames.

Answer (score 4):

Send multi file to a file(**textall.txt**):

```
cat *.txt > textall.txt
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006581/how-to-append-contents-of-multiple-files-into-one-file/70161007#comment74383382_18006605

Comment: It does not seem to matter?

Answer (score 3):

If the original file contains non-printable characters, they will be lost when using the cat command.  Using 'cat -v', the non-printables will be converted to visible character strings, but the output file would still not contain the actual non-printables characters in the original file.  With a small number of files, an alternative might be to open the first file in an editor (e.g. vim) that handles non-printing characters.  Then maneuver to the bottom of the file and enter ":r second_file_name".  That will pull in the second file, including non-printing characters.  The same could  be done for additional files.  When all files have been read in, enter ":w".  The end result is that the first file will now contain what it did originally, plus the content of the files that were read in.

Comment: This isn't very scriptable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append contents of 3 files into one file, then the following command will be a good choice:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | tee -a file4 > /dev/null
```

It will combine the contents of all files into file4, throwing console output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Why `tee`? And what is `-a` for? It would improve your answer if you would use long versions of the switches.