# Why is 'cat' sorting differently based on where I specify a "*" in a set of filenames?

Tags: terminal, cat

I have three sets of files:

```
a1.txt, a2.txt, ... a10.txt
b1_m1.txt, b2_m1.txt, ... b10_m1.txt
b1_m2.txt, b2_m2.txt, ... b10_m2.txt
```

I want to concatenate all three together,  per set; I don't care in which order, as long as they're the same across sets. So I do:

```
cat ./output/a*.txt > ./results/a.txt
cat ./output/b*_m1.txt > ./results/b_m1.txt
cat ./output/b*_m2.txt > ./results/b_m2.txt
```

...and now, it appears that while the a* files are concatenated like so:

```
a0.txt, a1.txt, ... a10.txt
```

the two sets of b* files are concatenated like so:

```
b0_m1.txt, b10_m1.txt, b1_m1.txt, ...
```

Is that right? Why does it happen? How do I make both sets of files sort the same way? (Still working on that one, might find the answer myself!). Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your locale, but it's most likely because `.`, `0`, and `_` are encoded as 46, 48, and 95 (as happens in ASCII). That means that a name that starts with `a1.` should occur before one that starts with `a10`, but a name that starts with `b10` should occur before a name that starts with `b1_`.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve with `> some_file_pattern*.txt`?

Comment: Argh, those stars shouldn't be there, just '> b_m2.txt!' I checked and double checked, sorry!

Comment: I think I understand your answer, though. So going forward, the solution is simply to make sure all my files end exactly the same way after the number. But right now, I have about 12 million files all named this way...

Comment: What I would do is to create a file (or a stream) of all file names, add a column with the order, apply `sort -n` to the file, drop the column, and use that order. The process would look a bit like `find -name 'b*_m1.txt' | sed -e 's/b\([0-9]+\)_m1\.txt/\1\t\0/' | sort -n | cut -f 2 | xargs cat > b_m1.txt`, but I obviously haven't tested it. In any case, you might want to ask this question on [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), who are much better at formulating scripts like these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did eventually find a solution using sort and a for loop... I'll answer my own question for posterity!

Comment: As I understand it, it is the _shell_ (`sh`, `bash`, and so on) that performs wildcard expansion. Your question is (mostly) unrelated to `cat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually sort out the ordering, using freddythunder's answer here:

[How to append contents of multiple files into one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006581/how-to-append-contents-of-multiple-files-into-one-file)

This will concatenate both sets of files in numerical order:

```
for i in {0..N}; do cat "./output/a$i.txt" >> ./results/a.txt; done

for i in {0..N}; do cat "./output/b${i}_m1.txt" >> ./results/b.txt; done
```

where *N* is the total number of files.