# How to merge multiple CSV files into one using terminal on MAC OS?

Tags: macos, csv, terminal

I have the directory with 20 csv files. They all have same headers. I want to merge these csv files into one file. When I'm working on windows, I just open cmd, go to the right directory and use this command:

```
 copy *.csv combined-files.csv
```

It does the job on Windows. I can't run this command on mac's terminal as command doesn't exist on Mac. How do I rewrite this Windows command so it does the same job on Mac OS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46490017/1801544 ?

Answer (score 20):

Easiest I can think of, which would be similar to the Windows version is:

```
cat *.csv > combined-files.csv
```

Note that the headers would be repeated throughout the `combined-files.csv` if they are contained in all the .csv-files. Just like the solution you posted for Windows.

Comment: I like the way you think !

Answer (score 7):

To concatenate all files into a single file, you can use the following awk command to consolidate the content.
This will ignore the header content though

```
awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv > consolidated.csv
```

The awk command assumes that all the files are in one directory.
If all of your files are in different directories, you can use the below command to bring it together into one directory

```
find . -name \*.csv -exec cp {} newdir/ \;
```